# How do two Poisson Processes affect each other?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Widgets of Type A arrive with Poisson Process with arrival rate $\lambda_A$, and, for Type B, with arrival rate $\lambda_B$ (independent).

During $t,$ there have been $b$ arrivals of Type B. What are the expected arrivals of Type A+B in time frame $t$?

Does one simply take the given value $b,$ and add to that the expected arrivals for process A?:

$$b+t \times \lambda_A$$

Comment: Assuming that both processes are independent, you can do like that. otherwise, it is inconclusive unless some auxiliary conditions are assumed.

Comment: thanks but why do you not post this as an answer, but as a comment?

Comment: I usually post a comment when I think the answer lacks the required details to be an answer...

Comment: Wuschel: You could transform this into an acceptable question by adding the information @sos440 suggested.

Comment: @did Ok i added the indep. assumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $N_t=N^A_t+N^B_t$ implies $\mathbb E(N_t\mid N^B_t=b)=\mathbb E(N^A_t\mid N^B_t=b)+b$. If furthermore the processes $N^A$ and $N^B$ are independent, then $\mathbb E(N^A_t\mid N^B_t=b)=\mathbb E(N^A_t)=\lambda_At$.

Thus, in your setting, $\mathbb E(N_t\mid N^B_t=b)=b+\lambda_At$.